# Configure global constraints with SpringBoot and GORM

Tags: grails, groovy, spring-boot, grails-orm

I am trying to add Gorm in Spring Boot, and I am struggling to configure global constraints and mapping.

In Grails, it is possible to add in Config.groovy:

```
grails.gorm.default.constraints = {
'*'(nullable: true, size: 1..20)
...
}
```

But I cannot manage to find the equivalent in SpringBoot. Also, I didn't find any documentation on how to configure Gorm with SpringBoot... Any idea?

Comment: What version of Grails please.

Comment: I am using Spring Boot 1.3.2 and Gorm stand alone 5.0.0.RC1. I am trying to use Gorm with SpringBoot

Comment: I'm assuming you are using the spring boot, hibernate, gorm starter?  (e.g. gorm-hibernate4-spring-boot)

Comment: BTW...the current version of Grails uses Spring boot and Gradle under the covers.  Also you can configure it to generate headless REST services etc. also.

Comment: I know, I've been using Grails for ages and I love it... But I am working on an existing project, and I need an ORM there. Gorm standalone is definitely my prefferred choice, but I need to know about the default constraints and how to configure them in SpringBoot :/